# Jquery :eq() selector not working for me

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li:eq(3n+1)').css({backgroundColor:'#f00'});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mD6Hf/2/

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you seem to have confused jQuery's `eq()` selector with CSS' `:nth-child()` pseudo-selector.

To use a CSS selector for this (albeit in the context of jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li:nth-child(3n+1)').css({backgroundColor:'#f00'});
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mD6Hf/4/)

Using `filter()` you can use:

```
$('li').filter(
    function(i){
        if (i%3 + 1 == 1){
            return $(this);
        }
}).css('background-color','#f00');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mD6Hf/7/).

But I can't see how to do it with `eq()` since, so far as I can see, that's meant to return only one result (though I've not exhaustively read the whole jQuery API).

References:

- [`:nth-child selector()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Ok... 
I want to select 1,4,7,10,13 ....  elements and not their children if any...how to do that?

Comment: You want to select the `li` elements, but not any elements that those `li` elements might contain?

Comment: Yes...
This did the trick for me:
$('ul >:nth-child(3n+1)').css({backgroundColor:'#f00'});

Thanks for your suggesting :nth-child ... I didn't have it in mind..

Comment: You're quite welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help! Please remember to accept the answer that best helped you to reach your solution and, if you're able, up-vote those answers that were helpful or that you found informative. =)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use :eq() then try it this way:

```
$('ul li:eq(3)').css({backgroundColor:'#f00'});
```

:eq() is 0-based. Means that index 3 is the fourth element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that uses a little more jQuery to do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(i,el) {
        if (i%3==0)
        $(this).css({backgroundColor:'#f00'});
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mD6Hf/6/

This will work even if the browser doesn't support CSS3.